# Browser stops responding when databinding to a dropdown

Tags: c#, browser

net c# web form application.
when I tried to fill a drop down with a huge record, about 225000 records :), 
the browser stops responding. and showing  an error

```
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.
```

what I have to do? is this because of the huge amount of data? or any other problem? Please help..

Comment: 1. We can't help without seeing any code. 2. For the love of god don't fill a dropdown with 225k items, how would you expect that to be usable?

Comment: It is due to huge amount of data. You can use lazy load functionality with AJAX calls to achieve this. Also please don't expect a direct answer to this as your requirement is too broad. We can point you some tutorials and online references though

Comment: Which browser shows the error? Chrome? IE8? Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't think that 
**a normal Drop-down would be an ideal User Control for such an amount of data.**

The error is shown because of the DOM Rendering that is happening on the client-side is just taking so much time.

if you still want to use this control then you will need to implement **load on demand** logic for it. You'll need to create a new Dropdown User Control with a class that implements **IScriptControl** and on the client side you can control the rendering mechanism.

An explanation on how to do it: 
https://forums.asp.net/t/1503727.aspx?load+on+demand+combobox+